# Regular Expression for matching a string with different combinations

Tags: python, regex, r

I'n trying to match a string with the following different combinations using python

(here x's are digits of lenght 4)

```
W|MON-FRI|xxxx-xxxx 
W|mon-fri|xxxx-xxxx
W|MON-THU,SAT|xxxx-xxxx
W|mon-thu,sat|xxxx-xxxx
W|MON|xxxx-xxxx
```

Here the first part and the last is static, second part is can have any of the combinations as shown above, like sometime the days were separated by ',' or '-'.

I'm a newbie to Regular Expressions, I was googled on how regular expressions works, I can able to do the RE for bits & pieces of above expressions like matching the last part with `re.compile('(\d{4})-(\d{4})$')` and the first part with `re.compile('[w|W]')`.

I tried to match the 2nd part but couldn't succeeded with

```
new_patt = re.compile('(([a-zA-Z]{3}))([,-]?)(([a-zA-Z]{3})?))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is there an r tag on this?

Comment: Hi Grothendieck, In python official document it is like that, in many example they used r infront of every pattern with r.compile(r" ")

Comment: The r tag on SO means the R programming language.  Suggest you remove that tag from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can get everything in one go:

```
^W\|(?:\w{3}[-,]){0,2}\w{3}\|(?:\d{4}[-]?){2}$
```

With <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lN0mU6/2)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is easy to understand. But this RE is working for wrong length as well, as shown below

Comment: new_pat = re.compile(r'^W\|(?:\w{3}[-,]?)*\|(?:\d{4}[-]?)+$')

Comment: new_pat.match('W|monsdf,thussf,fri|1200-1300').group()

Comment: Output : 'W|monsdf,thussf,fri|1200-1300'

Comment: here the length of day is more than 3 for monsdf,thussf

Comment: It is taking string length as multiples of 3, like 3, 6, 9.......as word length, if we pass 4/5/7/8 length string, it is not matching with the pattern

Comment: this is happening with last part as well, the (digit)pattern is matching for 4,8,12 ....

Comment: @Thomos, is there any way to restrict it the length of string to 3 and digit to 4 only

Comment: @Kumar see edit, and please, next time try to avoid flooding ;)

Comment: Thanks Thomos. I just started using stackoverflow, so I couldn't able to do the comments in one shot effectively

Comment: @Kumar you should also accept the answer that helped you the most, it's the StackOverflow way of saying *thank you*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that should work:

```
pat = re.compile('^W\|(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?(,(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?)?\⎪\d{4}-\d{4}$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Note first how you can ignore the case to take care of lower and upper cases. In addition to the static text at the beginning and the numbers at the end, this regex matches a day of the week, followed by an optional dash+day of the week, followed by an optional sequence that contains a `,`and the previous sequence.

```
"^W\|(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?(,(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?)?\|\d{4}-\d{4}$"i
    ^ assert position at start of the string
    W matches the character W literally (case insensitive)
    \| matches the character | literally
    1st Capturing group (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
    2nd Capturing group (-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
        - matches the character - literally
        3rd Capturing group (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
    4th Capturing group (,(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?)?
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
        , matches the character , literally
        5th Capturing group (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
        6th Capturing group (-(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?
            Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
            - matches the character - literally
            7th Capturing group (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
    \| matches the character | literally
    \d{4} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
    - matches the character - literally
    \d{4} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
    $ assert position at end of the string
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

https://regex101.com/r/dW4dQ7/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your posts and comments,

At last I am able to satisfy my requirement with regular expressions
here it is

"^[w|W]\|(mon|sun|fri|thu|sat|wed|tue|[0-6])(-(mon|fri|sat|sun|wed|thu|tue|[0-6]))?(,(mon|fri|sat|sun|wed|thu|tue|[0-6]))*?\|(\d{4}-\d{4})$"img

I just tweaked the answer posted by Julien Spronck

Once again thanks all